# Why aren't flex items growing equally in this div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

- Trying to make my flex items to take up the div equally in `.sec-3` div. I've given both flex items `flex:1;` which should mean
  `flex-basis` and `flex-grow:` to be 1 and shrink 0?
- I've also tried to use `justify-content:space-between` which hasn't
  worked? Not sure why?

Any ideas?

Html

```
<div class="sec-3">
            <!-- iphone image  -->
        <div class="sec-3-flex">
        <!-- Iphone 1 image -->
            <picture>
                <!-- <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-iphone-1.jpg"> -->
                          <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/desktop/images/home_11.jpg">
                <img  id="iphone-2-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:50%">
            </picture>
            <div class="sales-copy-wrap">
                <h3>Get organized with events, tasks and notes.</h3>
                <p class="sales-copy">Now more then ever it is critical for smart professionals to stay up to date with important deadlines.</p>
            </div>              
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* SECTION THREE */
.sec-3 {
    background-color: #f1eeee;
    margin-top: -22px;
}
.sec-3-flex {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

 }
.sec-3-flex #iphone-2-img {
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-color: orange;   
    flex:1;

 }
.sec-3-flex .sales-copy-wrap {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex:1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a [**flex formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) is the parent-child relationship. Descendants of a flex container beyond the children are not flex items and will not accept flex properties.

More specifically, the `flex` property will work only when the parent element has `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`.

In your code, `.sec-3` has only one child, `.sec-3-flex`, and this child is not a flex item because the parent is not a flex container.

However. `.sec-3-flex` is a flex container. It has two flex items: `picture` and `.sales-copy-wrap`.

Only `.sales-copy-wrap` has `flex: 1`.

Add `flex: 1` to `picture` if you want both siblings to be equal width.

Giving `flex: 1` to the `img` child of `picture` does nothing because `picture` is not a flex container.

Comment: Ahh. Gotcha. Also, why isn't justify-content: space-around;  working?  I need the image and content to have space space distributed, is the width wrong?

Comment: `justify-content` aligns flex items through the distribution of space in the container. But you've given `flex: 1` to one of the items (`.sales-copy-wrap`). That makes this item consume all free space on the line. As a result, there's no space left for `justify-content` to distribute. Remove `flex: 1` and `justify-content` will work.